# Python subprocess wait() behaves differently on mavericks and Yosemite

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, osx-yosemite

I recently upgraded to Yosemite. And some of the Python scripts are hanging that used to run on Mavericks. My version is 2.7.8. I created a test case:

```
import subprocess
cat = subprocess.Popen(['top', '-l', '1'],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            )
cat.wait()
```

Runs on Maverics but hangs on Yosemite. When I interrupt on Yosemite, I see the following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
      cat.wait()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1376, in wait
      pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
      return func(*args)
    KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any hint as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do something like `['top', '-l', '1', '-n', '0']` and check if this works. This will probably mean that the deadlock pointed @GoBusto is right.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to call `communicate()`. From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects):

> **`Popen.wait()`**
>
> Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return `returncode` attribute.
>
> **Warning:** This will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it
>   blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use
>   [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to avoid that.