# call a perl script with options within a python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know there are other posts with same question, but I am unable to run a perl script within my python script referring those posts.

Here is the excerpt from my code:

```
var1 = "-proj xyz"
var2 = "-c groups"
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "some_perl_script.pl", var1, var2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2.stdin.write(var1)
proc2.stdin.write(var2)
proc2.stdin.close()
proc2.wait()
```

Note: I'm supposed to run: ./some_perl_script.pl -c groups -proj xyz

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854021/python-subprocess-wait-behaves-differently-on-mavericks-and-yosemite/26854258#26854258), although I can't be certain without more details about what your actual problem is.

Comment: Why are you sending the contents of `var1` and `var2` to your `Popen` command, **and** writing them to stdin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `"-proj xyz"` as a single argument, instead of two. In other words, instead of this:

```
./some_perl_script.pl -c groups -proj xyz
```

… you're doing the equivalent of this:

```
./some_perl_script.pl '-c groups' '-proj xyz'
```

So, when the perl script goes looking to see if any argument is `-c`, none of them are, because  `-c groups` is not `-c`.

Of course in some cases you'll get away with this; most argument parsers that treat `-cfoo` and `-c foo` the same will also treat `'-c foo'` the same. But I'm guessing any parser that's looking for arguments like `-proj` isn't such a case.

So, if you really need these option/argument pairs to each be in a separate variable for some reason, try this:

```
var1 = ["-proj", "xyz"]
var2 = ["-c", "groups"]
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "some_perl_script.pl"] + var1 + var2,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```